# Why does this work in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to understand why something works the way it does in jQuery.
When I want to apply a jQuery extension, for example [datatables](http://datatables.net/), I run the command:

```
$("#some_id").datatables(.. parameters ..);
```

I don't know why this works, obviously the DOM element didn't have a method `datatables()` beforehand.

Thanks!

Comment: you  might have included dataTable plugin in your code... :)

Comment: You should do some reading: [Types: jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for that is because you are not making this call on DOM element - you are making it on **jQuery object** that stores the information on the DOM objects it should influence.

And the reason `.datatables()` is available is that some plugin (probably [DataTables](http://datatables.net/)) made it accessible in the way similar to this:

```
jQuery.fn.my_foo_func = function(){
    console.log(jQuery(this));
};
```

If you apply the above, you will be able to do something like that:

```
$("#some_id").my_foo_func();
```

which will pass to the console the jQuery object(s) on which you invoked it.

Is it clear enough?

Comment: I was just writing very similar answer :) Just one more useful link - a great starting point for understanding jQuery plugins: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring.

Comment: @WTK: Thanks. Indeed this is helpful and more detailed description on how to write jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 5):

`$("#some_id")` does not return a HTML DOM element, it returns a JQuery object wrapping it.

This JQuery object does have the datatables method.

Comment: OP said: " _I don't know why **this works**_ ". You did not answer the question.

Comment: @Tadeck: from the question (`obviously the DOM element didn't have a method...`). So this explains it IMHO.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Maybe you are right, but I do not see connection between "DOM element didn't have a method..." in question and "it is not DOM element" and "JQuery object does not have this method" in the answer. Maybe some details on how this method appeared and why does it work, even though jQuery nor DOM element doesn't have this method?

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `$("#some_id")` you no longer have a DOM object but a jQuery object.
The DOM object is reachable with `$("#some_id")[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You installed a plugin which added a method, .datatables(), to the [jQuery() object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), often abbreviated as $(). If you're interested in creating your own jQuery() object methods, [here's a Google search to get you started](http://www.google.ca/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery%20create%20method).